# Calculate difference neighboring rows same key

Tags: python, pandas

Stuck on an section of an assignment using turnstile data from NY MTA. Here is pretty much was is being asked.

The ENTRIES and EXITS fields hold raw counts that do not reset to zero each week. We would like to know how many entries and exits there are in the 4-hour periods. To calculate this, we need to calculate the difference between neighboring rows that have the same (UNIT, C/A, SCP) key. Create NUM_ENTRIES and NUM_EXITS columns that store these numbers.

Hints:

The shift method will be useful.
It will be easier to use groupby when doing the shift as it will respect boundaries between subunits. The level argument will help define the subunits.
Most of the counters count up, but there are some that count down. How should you handle those cases? Fix this for extra credit.

my code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv("turnstile_161126.txt")
timestamp =pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'] + ' ' + df['TIME'])
df.insert(3, 'TIMESTAMP', timestamp)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df = df.set_index(['UNIT','C/A','SCP','TIMESTAMP'])

                STATION LINENAME    DIVISION    DATE    TIME    DESC    ENTRIES EXITS
UNIT    C/A SCP TIMESTAMP                               
R051    A002    02-00-00    2016-11-19 03:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/19/2016  03:00:00    REGULAR 5924658 2007780
2016-11-19 07:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/19/2016  07:00:00    REGULAR 5924672 2007802
2016-11-19 11:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/19/2016  11:00:00    REGULAR 5924738 2007908
2016-11-19 15:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/19/2016  15:00:00    REGULAR 5924979 2007980
2016-11-19 19:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/19/2016  19:00:00    REGULAR 5925389 2008056
2016-11-19 23:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/19/2016  23:00:00    REGULAR 5925614 2008081
2016-11-20 03:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/20/2016  03:00:00    REGULAR 5925684 2008096
2016-11-20 07:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/20/2016  07:00:00    REGULAR 5925688 2008113
2016-11-20 11:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/20/2016  11:00:00    REGULAR 5925755 2008191
2016-11-20 15:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/20/2016  15:00:00    REGULAR 5925937 2008260
2016-11-20 19:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/20/2016  19:00:00    REGULAR 5926232 2008332
2016-11-20 23:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/20/2016  23:00:00    REGULAR 5926394 2008367
2016-11-21 03:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/21/2016  03:00:00    REGULAR 5926425 2008378
2016-11-21 07:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/21/2016  07:00:00    REGULAR 5926440 2008420
2016-11-21 11:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/21/2016  11:00:00    REGULAR 5926622 2008741
2016-11-21 15:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/21/2016  15:00:00    REGULAR 5926872 2008851
2016-11-21 19:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/21/2016  19:00:00    REGULAR 5927775 2008927
2016-11-21 23:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/21/2016  23:00:00    REGULAR 5928130 2008976
2016-11-22 03:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/22/2016  03:00:00    REGULAR 5928180 2008982
2016-11-22 07:00:00 59 ST   NQR456W BMT 11/22/2016  07:00:00    REGULAR 5928197 2009028
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can just use [DataFrame.shift()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

You can simply subtract the shifted column values from the original column values and store them in the new columns:

```
df['NUM_ENTRIES'] = df.ENTRIES - df.ENTRIES.shift(1)
df['NUM_EXITS'] = df.EXITS - df.EXITS.shift(1)
```